# Using sas or sql add new records to table based on monthly date variables

Tags: sql, insert, sas, rows

I need to add records/rows to an existing table, based on values of a couple fields.  The rows are basically the range of months for each different id - most id's will have multiple months but some only one month.

I have a first_date field and a last_date field and need to fill in rows for however intervening months are between the two dates and creating a "time id" for the row identifying that month.

Current:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using for summary you can use FREQ total_months; in most procs or in proc freq is it WEIGHT.

I you really need to expand I think this will suffice.

```
data expand;
   set <data-name>;
   do time_id = 1 to total_months;
      output;
      end;
   run;
```

Comment: Starting with the simplest first - I really think this has done it - Thanks data_null!

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're going to need is an additional table, a dimension or mapping table, that will give you information on those dates/months. Think you can then join on it a few times to get your complete list.

Here's what I did:

```
    CREATE TABLE #tblCurrent 
  (ID INT,
  First_Date VARCHAR(9),
  Last_Date VARCHAR(9),
  TotalMonths INT,
  VAR1 INT,
  VAR2 INT)

  INSERT INTO #tblCurrent
  SELECT 123,'01jan2015','01mar2015',3,5,2
  union 
  SELECT 124,'01jul2015','01aug2015',2,5,2
  union 
  SELECT 125,'01jan2015','01jan2015',1,5,2
```

This was to just create a table mimicking yours...

```
CREATE TABLE #Month
  ([MonthName] VARCHAR(9),
  MonthRank INT)

  INSERT INTO #Month
  SELECT '01jan2015', 1
    union SELECT '01feb2015', 2
    union SELECT '01mar2015', 3
    union SELECT '01apr2015', 4
    union SELECT '01may2015', 5
    union SELECT '01jun2015', 6
    union SELECT '01jul2015', 7
    union SELECT '01aug2015', 8
    union SELECT '01sep2015', 9
    union SELECT '01oct2015', 10
    union SELECT '01nov2015', 11
    union SELECT '01dec2015', 12
```

This was to create a table with month information, like the order/rank.

```
  SELECT c.*, m3.MonthRank Time_ID
  FROM #tblCurrent c
  JOIN #Month m ON c.First_Date = m.[MonthName]
  JOIN #Month m2 ON c.Last_Date = m2.[MonthName]
  JOIN #Month m3 ON m3.MonthRank >= m.MonthRank and m3.MonthRank <=m2.MonthRank
  ORDER BY ID, m3.MonthRank
```

This third step pulls in info on the first month (join m), the last month (join m2) and then all the months in between (m3).

If you are going to continue to use the '01jan2015' style of dates, it would probably be useful to build a date dimension table to store a bunch of relevant info in columns.... month, year, etc..

Answer (score 0):

A far more concise response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36222217/6111039

---

The code below should take care of the hard part. See http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/enumerate.htm for how to handle time_id.

```
/*your dataset*/
data tempy;
   input id fd $ ld $ total_months time_id;
   datalines;
        123 jan mar 3 .
        124 jul aug 2 .
        125 jan jan 1 .
    ;
run;

/*make a copy of it*/
data tempy2;
    set tempy;
run;

/*select the total_months and id variables into lists*/
proc sql noprint;
    select total_months into: months_list
    separated by " "
    from tempy;
quit;

%put &months_list.;

proc sql noprint;
    select id into: ids_list
    separated by " "
    from tempy;
quit;

%put &ids_list.;


%macro inserter;

    /*for every row in the original dataset, keep track of id and how many total_months it has*/
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&months_list.));
    %let this_id = %scan(&ids_list., &i.);
    %let this_many_months = %scan(&months_list., &i.);

        /*insert the same observation into the original dataset (total_months - 1) times for each row*/
        %do j = 1 %to (&this_many_months. - 1);

            proc sql;
                insert into tempy select distinct * from tempy2 (where = (id = &this_id.));
            quit;

        %end;
    %end;

    /*sort*/
    proc sort data = tempy;
        by id;
    run;

%mend inserter;

%inserter;
```

Note that I just input the first_date and last_date variables as strings here to save time. You can use the month() function with date variables to get information you will find useful for tackling time_id (e.g., month(01jul2015) = 7).